Papers regarding the use of radio in brittle stars
After stumbling on this article, I have been looking for additional research into the possible use of radio by sea stars for some time now.
However, I haven’t been able to find anything regarding the subject, so I’m wondering if anyone here knows of any papers either confirming or disproving the use of radio in brittle stars.

What were your search terms? Try  - use of "radio" frequencies by brittle stars, with the quotes. That was the only search I did and I got one result.

I wasn't able to find anything at all on this subject, either with Google Scholar or Pubmed.

The only Pubmed hit for '"brittle star" radio' is referring to radio-isotopes, not radio frequency communication/sensing
similarly, Google Scholar hits for '"brittle star" radio' give mostly stuff about radioisotopes and radiolabeling, while '"brittle star" "radio frequency"' covers topics like use of imaging and tracking.

I looked at the Google Scholar profile of the principal investigator of the DARPA grant, and noticed only these relevant pubs:
Thackston, Kyle A., Dimitri D. Deheyn, and Daniel F. Sievenpiper. “Limitations on Electromagnetic Communication by Vibrational Resonances in Biological Systems.” Physical Review E 101, no. 6 (June 1, 2020): 062401. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.101.062401.
———. “Simulation of Electric Fields Generated from Microtubule Vibrations.” Physical Review E 100, no. 2 (August 15, 2019): 022410. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.100.022410.
The first paper looks particularly relevant: here is the (abridged) abstract:

Previous research in biology and physics speculates that high-frequency electromagnetic fields may be an unexplored method of cellular and subcellular communication. The predominant theory for generating electric fields in the cell is mechanical vibration of charged or polar biomolecules such as cell membranes or microtubules. The challenge to this theory is explaining how high-frequency vibrations would not be overdamped by surrounding biological media. ... While many resonators have been studied and simulated, the general limitations on communication imposed by energy transfer arguments have not been considered ... We determine the flexing mode of microtubules as an identified resonance in the literature which meets our criteria. Our results
suggest the major obstacle to meeting our criteria for effective electromagnetic communication is the trade-off between the Q [quality] factor and the plasma frequency: Resonators must be large enough to have a large Q factor, but small enough to resonate at frequencies greater than the plasma frequency.

To me this sounds like "our ideas didn't work out [DARPA projects are supposed to be high risk, so many should be expected to fail!], but here's the beginning of a theoretical framework for why they didn't work and what avenues someone interested in this area should pursue ..."
